# Can't change height of UINavigationBar in iOS 11

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement something similar to the new App Store's status bar in the 'Today' tab on iPhone X. 
[App Store - Today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itxMC.jpg)

So just wondering what is the implementation. I tried to changing the height of navigation bar/overlaying a translucent UIView over the status bar, but none seems satisfactory given that the bar only exist on iPhone X. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create class for navigation bar

```
class NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        for subview in self.subviews {
            let stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)

            if stringFromClass.contains("BarBackground") {
                subview.frame.origin.y = -20
                subview.frame.size.height = 64
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and create navigation bar with the required size

```
let navigationBar = NavigationBar(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,
                                                                        y: 20),
                                                        size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width,
                                                                     height: 30)))
       navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
       self.view .addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Comment: But this does not work if you have a UITableViewController as your View Controller right?

Comment: @ErvinTham View controller