# How to add navigation bar button without using navigation controller from storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11, iphone-x

I'm having issues adding navigation bar button to a UINavigationBar directly without using UINavigationController.
The way it appears when using with UINavigationController on iPhoneX, is different from what it looks when i directly add an UINavigationBar. 
Even if i set the height of navigationBar manually, the background color and bar button still stick to the top.

**Using UINavigationBar**

[image]

**After adjusting height or even using SafeAreaInset to set bar height**
[image]

**using UINavigationController -> desired result**
[image]

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646278/5362916

Comment: I usually embed the controller in a navigation controller (even if it's a single controller with no intention of navigating), it's much easier that way.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi That's not the correct way of fixing it. If we hardcode the height it will distort for other devices.

Comment: @the4kman Previously i was using it with UINavigationController only, But now i'm using a container view below the navigation bar, where i'm loading another controller on selecting a menu item. The new controller is also a navigation controller, so two navigation controllers are causing issues.